# Encontrar class de um elemento criado dinamicamente

Tags: javascript

Chamado de priority Nav, uma lib que coloca os items execendentes dentro de um novo drop-down, chamado "More" esse dropdown é criado dinamicamente em javascript puro assim que é preciso. Nele aparece um button com a class **js-nav-toggle**. Eu estou experimentando algumas coisas, e gostaria de alterar algumas coisas nesse button, com javascript puro, estou fazendo um teste tentando encontrar a classe **js-nav-toggle** que definitivamente está no documento, mas só dá indefinido.

https://codepen.io/johnquimera/pen/qKLpPe

Eu uso esse código que funciona bem em outros elementos que são escritos manualmente do documento.

`const list = document.getElementsByClassName("js-nav-toggle");
list.style.backgroundColor = "red";`

o que poderia está acontecendo?

Comment: Estranho, pq eu abri o console na própria página do codepen que vc passou, eu consigo acessá-lo e mexer no css dele.

Comment: @Leandro Você conseguiu alterar o css do button com a class  "js-nav-toggle" dinamicamente com javascript puro?

Comment: É na verdade não, foi pelo ccs do console mesmo, o que é estranho, pq a classe existe. Teria que dar uma olhada na documentação para ver certinho, como é criado este elemento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variável `list` é uma lista de nós da classe `.js-nav-toggle`:

```
const list = document.getElementsByClassName("js-nav-toggle");
```

Você não consegue alterar a lista de uma vez. É preciso iterar cada elemento da lista, e você pode fazer isso `for`:

```
for(let x=0; x<list.length; x++){
   list[x].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Mas se for apenas 1 elemento, você pode usar o índice `[0]`:

```
list[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Pode também usar o `querySelector` (se for apenas 1 elemento) ou `querySelectorAll` (1 ou mais):

```
document.querySelector(".js-nav-toggle");
```

Já o `querySelectorAll` também cria uma lista de nós igualmente ao `getElementsByClassName`, e se for apenas 1 elemento, você também usa o índice `[0]`:

```
const list = document.querySelectorAll(".js-nav-toggle")[0];
list.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Ou:

```
const list = document.querySelectorAll(".js-nav-toggle");
list[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

No entanto, se for apenas 1 elemento, faz mais sentido usar o `querySelector`:

```
const list = document.querySelector(".js-nav-toggle");
list.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Se for apenas 1 elemento, não faz sentido criar uma lista de nós.

**Exemplo:**

```js
"remove"in Element.prototype||(Element.prototype.remove=function(){this.parentNode&&this.parentNode.removeChild(this)}),!function(){"use strict";var t,e,i,n,r=window,o=document,s=Object,a=null,h=!0,l=!1,d=" ",u="Element",f="create"+u,p="DOMTokenList",c="__defineGetter__",m="defineProperty",g="class",v="List",b=g+v,w="rel",y=w+v,C="div",A="length",x="contains",F="apply",L="HTML",T=("item "+x+" add remove toggle toString toLocaleString").split(d),S=T[2],I=T[3],z=T[4],H="prototype",N=m in s||c in s[H]||a,j=function(t,e,i,n){s[m]?s[m](t,e,{configurable:l===N?h:!!n,get:i}):t[c](e,i)},W=function(e,i){var n=this,r=[],o={},a=0,u=0,f=function(){if(a>=u)for(;a>u;++u)(function(t){j(n,t,function(){return p(),r[t]},l)})(u)},p=function(){var t,n,s=arguments,l=/\s+/;if(s[A])for(n=0;n<s[A];++n)if(l.test(s[n]))throw t=new SyntaxError('String "'+s[n]+'" '+x+" an invalid character"),t.code=5,t.name="InvalidCharacterError",t;for(r=(""+e[i]).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"").split(l),""===r[0]&&(r=[]),o={},n=0;n<r[A];++n)o[r[n]]=h;a=r[A],f()};return p(),j(n,A,function(){return p(),a}),n[T[6]]=n[T[5]]=function(){return p(),r.join(d)},n.item=function(t){return p(),r[t]},n[x]=function(t){return p(),!!o[t]},n[S]=function(){p[F](n,t=arguments);for(var t,s,l=0,u=t[A];u>l;++l)s=t[l],o[s]||(r.push(s),o[s]=h);a!==r[A]&&(a=r[A]>>>0,e[i]=r.join(d),f())},n[I]=function(){p[F](n,t=arguments);for(var t,s={},l=0,u=[];l<t[A];++l)s[t[l]]=h,delete o[t[l]];for(l=0;l<r[A];++l)s[r[l]]||u.push(r[l]);r=u,a=u[A]>>>0,e[i]=r.join(d),f()},n[z]=function(e,i){return p[F](n,[e]),t!==i?i?(n[S](e),h):(n[I](e),l):o[e]?(n[I](e),l):(n[S](e),h)},function(t,e){if(e)for(var i=0;7>i;++i)e(t,T[i],{enumerable:l})}(n,s[m]),n},q=function(t,e,i){j(t[H],e,function(){var t,n=this,r=c+m+e;if(n[r])return t;if(n[r]=h,l===N){for(var s,a=q.mirror=q.mirror||o[f](C),d=a.childNodes,u=d[A],p=0;u>p;++p)if(d[p]._R===n){s=d[p];break}s||(s=a.appendChild(o[f](C))),t=W.call(s,n,i)}else t=new W(n,i);return j(n,e,function(){return t}),delete n[r],t},h)};if(r[p])e=o[f](C)[b],H=r[p][H],e[S][F](e,T),2>e[A]&&(i=H[S],n=H[I],H[S]=function(){for(var t=0,e=arguments;t<e[A];++t)i.call(this,e[t])},H[I]=function(){for(var t=0,e=arguments;t<e[A];++t)n.call(this,e[t])}),e[z](v,l)&&(H[z]=function(e,i){var n=this;return n[(i=t===i?!n[x](e):i)?S:I](e),!!i});else{if(N)try{j({},"support")}catch(V){N=l}W.polyfill=h,r[p]=W,q(r[u],b,g+"Name"),q(r[L+"Link"+u],y,w),q(r[L+"Anchor"+u],y,w),q(r[L+"Area"+u],y,w)}}(),Date.now||(Date.now=function(){return(new Date).getTime()}),function(){"use strict";for(var t=["webkit","moz"],e=0;e<t.length&&!window.requestAnimationFrame;++e){var i=t[e];window.requestAnimationFrame=window[i+"RequestAnimationFrame"],window.cancelAnimationFrame=window[i+"CancelAnimationFrame"]||window[i+"CancelRequestAnimationFrame"]}if(/iP(ad|hone|od).*OS 6/.test(window.navigator.userAgent)||!window.requestAnimationFrame||!window.cancelAnimationFrame){var n=0;window.requestAnimationFrame=function(t){var e=Date.now(),i=Math.max(n+16,e);return setTimeout(function(){t(n=i)},i-e)},window.cancelAnimationFrame=clearTimeout}}(),function(t,e,i){"use strict";function n(t,e,n,o){n=n||"width";var a,h,l,f=(e.match(d)||[])[2],p="px"===f?1:u[f+"toPx"],c=/r?em/i;if(p||c.test(f)&&!o)t=p?t:"rem"===f?s:"fontSize"===n?t.parentNode||t:t,p=p||parseFloat(r(t,"fontSize")),l=parseFloat(e)*p;else{a=t.style,h=a[n];try{a[n]=e}catch(m){return 0}l=a[n]?parseFloat(r(t,n)):0,a[n]=h!==i?h:null}return l}function r(t,e){var i,o,s,a=/^top|bottom/,u=["paddingTop","paddingBottom","borderTop","borderBottom"],f,p,c=4;if(i=h?h(t)[e]:(o=t.style["pixel"+e.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+e.slice(1)])?o+"px":"fontSize"===e?n(t,"1em","left",1)+"px":t.currentStyle[e],s=(i.match(d)||[])[2],"%"===s&&l)if(a.test(e)){for(f=(p=t.parentNode||t).offsetHeight;c--;)f-=parseFloat(r(p,u[c]));i=parseFloat(i)/100*f+"px"}else i=n(t,i);else("auto"===i||s&&"px"!==s)&&h?i=0:s&&"px"!==s&&!h&&(i=n(t,i)+"px");return i}var o=e.createElement("test"),s=e.documentElement,a=e.defaultView,h=a&&a.getComputedStyle,l,d=/^(-?[\d+\.\-]+)([a-z]+|%)$/i,u={},f=[1/25.4,1/2.54,1/72,1/6],p=["mm","cm","pt","pc","in","mozmm"],c=6;for(s.appendChild(o),h&&(o.style.marginTop="1%",l="1%"===h(o).marginTop);c--;)u[p[c]+"toPx"]=f[c]?f[c]*u.inToPx:n(o,"1"+p[c]);s.removeChild(o),o=i,t.Length={toPx:n}}(this,this.document);var gn={};gn.optimizedResize=function(){function t(){r||(r=!0,window.requestAnimationFrame?window.requestAnimationFrame(e):setTimeout(e,66))}function e(){n.forEach(function(t){t()}),r=!1}function i(t){t&&n.push(t)}var n=[],r=!1;return{add:function(e){n.length||window.addEventListener("resize",t),i(e)}}}(),gn.getOuterWidth=function(t){var e=/\d/,i=t.offsetWidth,n=t.currentStyle||getComputedStyle(t),r=null===e.exec(n.marginLeft)?"0px":n.marginLeft,o=null===e.exec(n.marginRight)?"0px":n.marginRight;return i+=parseInt(Length.toPx(t,r))+parseInt(Length.toPx(t,o))},gn.getOuterHeight=function(t){var e=/\d/,i=t.offsetHeight,n=t.currentStyle||getComputedStyle(t),r=null===e.exec(n.marginTop)?"0px":n.marginTop,o=null===e.exec(n.marginBottom)?"0px":n.marginBottom;return i+=parseInt(Length.toPx(t,r))+parseInt(Length.toPx(t,o))},gn.isNodeList=function(t){return"undefined"!=typeof t.item},gn.append=function(t,e){var i=gn.isNodeList(t)?t:[t],n;if("undefined"!=typeof e.nodeType&&1===e.nodeType)for(n=i.length;n--;)i[n].appendChild(e);else if("string"==typeof e)for(n=i.length;n--;)i[n].insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",e);else if(gn.isNodeList(e)){var r=document.createDocumentFragment();for(n=e.length;n--;)r.insertBefore(e[n],r.firstChild);for(var o=i.length;o--;)i[o].appendChild(r)}},gn.prepend=function(t,e){var i=gn.isNodeList(t)?t:[t],n;if("undefined"!=typeof e.nodeType&&1===e.nodeType)for(n=i.length;n--;)i[n].insertBefore(e,i[n].firstChild);else if("string"==typeof e)for(n=i.length;n--;)i[n].insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",e);else if(gn.isNodeList(e)){var r=document.createDocumentFragment();for(n=e.length;n--;)r.insertBefore(e[n],r.firstChild);for(var o=i.length;o--;)i[o].insertBefore(r,i[o].firstChild)}},gn.extend=function(){for(var t,e,i,n=arguments[0]||{},r=1,o=arguments.length;o>r;r++)if(null!==(t=arguments[r]))for(e in t)i=t[e],n!==i&&void 0!==i&&(n[e]=i);return n};/**
  * priorityNav native (works with go-native)
  * 
  * v0.1.0
  * @author William Lin
  * @license The MIT License (MIT)
  * https://github.com/ganlanyuan/priorityNav
  */
var priorityNav=function(){"use strict";function t(t){t=gn.extend({nav:".priority-nav",button:"more",showAll:0,hideAll:0},t||{});var i=document.querySelectorAll(t.nav),n=[];if(0!==i.length){for(var r=i.length;r--;){var o=t;o.nav=i[r];var s=new e(o);n.unshift(s)}return n}}function e(t){this.nav=t.nav,this.visibleContainer=this.nav.querySelector("ul"),this.visibleItems=this.visibleContainer.children,this.fragment=document.createDocumentFragment(),this.buttonContent=t.button,this.showAll=t.showAll,this.hideAll=t.hideAll,this.bp=[],this.bpV=[],this.bpH=[],this.initialized=!1,this.nav.classList.add("js-priority-nav"),this.getBreakpoints(),this.updateNav();var e=this;gn.optimizedResize.add(function(){e.updateNav()})}return e.prototype={init:function(){this.nav.querySelector("ul").classList.add("js-nav-visible"),gn.prepend(this.nav,'<button class="js-nav-toggle" data-count="">'+this.buttonContent+"</button>"),gn.append(this.nav,'<ul class="js-nav-hidden is-hidden"></ul>'),this.hiddenContainer=this.nav.querySelector(".js-nav-hidden"),this.hiddenItems=this.hiddenContainer.children,this.btn=this.nav.querySelector(".js-nav-toggle"),this.btnWidth=gn.getOuterWidth(this.btn);var t=this;this.btn.addEventListener("click",function(){t.hiddenContainer.classList.toggle("is-hidden")}),this.initialized=!0},destory:function(){if(this.initialized){if(this.bpH.length>0){for(;this.bpH.length>0;)this.appendItemsToFragment();this.visibleContainer.appendChild(this.fragment)}this.nav.classList.remove("js-priority-nav"),this.visibleContainer.classList.remove("js-nav-visible"),this.hiddenContainer.remove(),this.btn.remove(),this.initialized=!1}},getBreakpoints:function(){for(var t=!1,e=this.visibleItems.length;e--;){t&&(this.visibleItems[e+1].style.display="none");var i=gn.getOuterWidth(this.visibleContainer)+1;this.bp.unshift(i),this.bpV.unshift(i),t=!0}for(var n=0,r=this.visibleItems.length;r>n;n++)this.visibleItems[n].style.display=""},prependItemsToFragment:function(){gn.prepend(this.fragment,this.visibleItems[this.bpV.length-1]),this.bpH.unshift(this.bpV[this.bpV.length-1]),this.bpV.splice(-1,1)},appendItemsToFragment:function(){gn.append(this.fragment,this.hiddenItems[0]),this.bpV.push(this.bpH[0]),this.bpH.shift()},updateNav:function(){if(this.windowWidth=window.innerWidth,this.outerWidth=gn.getOuterWidth(this.nav),this.outerWidth>=this.bp[this.bp.length-1]||this.windowWidth<this.showAll)this.destory();else{if(this.initialized||this.init(),this.availableSpace=this.outerWidth-this.btnWidth,0===this.hideAll||this.windowWidth>=this.hideAll)if(this.availableSpace<=this.bpV[this.bpV.length-1]){for(;this.availableSpace<=this.bpV[this.bpV.length-1];)this.prependItemsToFragment();this.hiddenContainer.insertBefore(this.fragment,this.hiddenContainer.firstChild)}else{for(this.hiddenItems=this.hiddenContainer.children;this.availableSpace>this.bpH[0];)this.appendItemsToFragment();this.visibleContainer.appendChild(this.fragment)}else{if(this.bpH.length===this.bp.length)return;for(;this.bpV.length>0;)this.prependItemsToFragment();this.hiddenContainer.insertBefore(this.fragment,this.hiddenContainer.firstChild)}this.currentCount=this.currentCount||0,this.count=this.bpH.length||0,this.count!==this.currentCount&&(this.currentCount=this.btn.getAttribute("data-count"),this.btn.setAttribute("data-count",this.count))}}},t}();
    priorityNav({
        nav: '.nav',
        hideAll: 300,
    });

  const list = document.getElementsByClassName("js-nav-toggle");
list[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

```css
@keyframes example {
    from {transform: scale(1);}
    to {transform: scale(1.2);}
}

html {
        font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    a {
        color: inherit;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .link {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #0fa5f0;
    }

    .link:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .container {
        max-width: 800px;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }

    ul {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    li {
        list-style: none;
    }

    .priority-nav {
        min-height: 37px;
        background-color: #0E8FE0;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    .priority-nav li {
        padding: 10px 13px;
    }

    .priority-nav button {
        padding: 10px;
        border-width: 0;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 11px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        background-color: #333;
        position: relative;
        overflow: visible;
    }

    .priority-nav button:before {
        content: attr(data-count);
        width: 23px;
        height: 23px;
        line-height: 23px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 50%;
        margin-left: -11px;
        margin-top: -11px;
        color: #412F08;
        background-color: #FFB822;
    
        animation: example 1s infinite;
    }

    .priority-nav .js-nav-hidden {
        background-color: #333;
        z-index: 3;
    }

    .nav-main-wrapper {
      display: table;
    }

    .nav-module {
      display: table-cell;
    }

    .nav-module.nav-main {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .priority-nav{position:relative}.priority-nav:after{content:'';clear:both;display:table}.priority-nav>ul{max-width:100%;overflow-x:auto}.priority-nav>ul>li{display:table-cell;white-space:nowrap}.priority-nav .is-hidden{visibility:hidden}.priority-nav.js-priority-nav ul{float:left;max-width:none;overflow-x:hidden}.priority-nav .js-nav-hidden{position:absolute;right:0;top:100%}.priority-nav .js-nav-hidden>li{display:list-item}.priority-nav .js-nav-toggle{position:absolute;right:0;height:100%;cursor:pointer}

/*# sourceMappingURL=priority-nav.css.map */
```

```html
<div class="container">

   
          <div class="nav priority-nav">
              <ul class="links">
                  <li><a href="">Entertainment</a></li>
                
                  <li><a href="">Sports</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Business</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Technology</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Nation</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Politics</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">World</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Opinion</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Obituaries</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Travel</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Life & Style</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Science</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>



    </div>
```

Comment: Não foi. Null. Tudo isso funciona com qualquer elemento que já esteja no documento, mas por alguma razão não está funcionando com elementos criado dinamicamente.

Comment: Rapaz... modifiquei o ex no code pen, funciona,  não entendo porque não está funcionando aqui no localhost.  https://codepen.io/johnquimera/pen/qKLpPe será conflito com jquery... vou testar.

Comment: falta de atenção minha. Eu estava colocando o **const list** acima do call **priorityNav** agora foi.

Comment: Eu já ia fazer outra pergunta que tem relação com essa. Sabe o botão "More", aquele bullet amarelo que mostra a contagem dos items. Eu gostaria de colocar uma especie de efeito "pulse" no botão quando um novo item fosse adicionado. Eu irei remover o contador.

Comment: não, apenas quando um novo item for adicionado.

Comment: Por "tempo todo" você quer dizer sempre que visível? Como você deve ter visto esse bullet é feito com um pseudo seletor, e é fácil remover ele, não, ele não vai ficar sempre pulsando, o pulso só vai ocorrer quando o window for resizado e um novo item do menu for adicionado. Sempre que o windows é resizado em live time, a quantidade de items vão sendo contada e adicionado ao bullet. É nesse esquema que o pulso deve ocorrer.
`
.priority-nav button:before {
    content: attr(data-count); /*bullet*/
}
`

Comment: Isso, sempre que for visível.

Comment: sim, pode ser, verei como fica. Acho que pode ser uma boa.

Comment: Adicionei na resposta.

Comment: Opa muito bom. perfeito. Vlw.

Answer (score 0):

Olá @John,

Vc quer mudar a cor da classe priority nav, isso?

Via css vc pode fazer:

```
.priority-nav{
  background-color:red!important;
}
```

ou

Se vc puder usar jquery, tente da seguinte forma:

```
$(".priority-nav").css({
   backgroundColor:'red'
});
```